# Numpy IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, numpy

My code:

```
import numpy as np
num_people = 2
x = np.zeros((1,75,1,1792,num_people))
for i in range(num_people):
  x[1,:,:,:,i]=np.arange(75,1,1792)
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-941de32daec2> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(num_people):
----> 2   x[1,:,:,:,i]=np.arange(75,1,1792)

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in Python's GOLDEN RULE - everything starts with zero. 
You made -

```
x = np.zeros((1,75,1,1792,num_people))
```

which says that x will have a shape of (1, 75, 1, 1792, 2)
and the first axis will only have 1 item, but while in for a loop when say -

`x[1,:,:,:,i]` you are asking for a 2nd item which doesn't even exist in the first axis,

So replace <del>`x[1,:,:,:,i]`</del> with `x[0,:,:,:,i]`

It would be really helpful if you understand the difference between shape and accessing the dimension. So shape 1 means you have only 1 item, but while accessing it you need to say give me 0th value(as everything starts from zero)

Comment: Python's golden rule? Don't you mean pretty much every programming language ever made?

Comment: Example R language - There is no such thing index ZERO, everything starts from 1.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. Guess I shouldn't speak so fast :P